# Why is my function using DOM resulting in undefined?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to using the DOM and am trying to create this function that creates a 16x16 grid in HTML. I am using JavaScript to create the HTML and CSS. However, whenever I return the function it is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```js
const cellSize = 16;

function createGrid(cellSize) {
  const container = document.querySelector('container');
  for (i=0; i<cellSize; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<cellSize; j++ ) {
          let row = document.createElement('div');
          row.classList.add('row');
          row.style.display = 'inline-block';
          row.style.cssText = 'height: 50px; width:50px;';
          row.style.border = 'solid';
          row.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
          }
    container.appendChild(row);
    return row; 
  }
};

console.log(createGrid());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<container>

</container>





</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `row` with a `let` statement inside the block of the inner `for` loop, and then returning it from *outside* that block. It's therefore `undefined`. The `let` declaration scopes its variables to the nearest enclosing block.

The variable `row` should be declared with `let` at the very top of the function, and the `return` statement (which doesn't seem really necessary anyway) should be outside the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

- The undefined result is due to the missing return within the function `createGrid`.
- The argument `cellSize` if hiding the constant `const cellSize = 16;`, so you need to decide how to pass that size.
- You're trying to return a `row` instead of variable `container`.

*This approach uses the constant `cellSize` and returns the created grid.*

```js
const cellSize = 16;

function createGrid() {
  const container = document.querySelector('container');
  for (i = 0; i < cellSize; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < cellSize; j++) {
      let row = document.createElement('div');
      row.classList.add('row');
      row.style.display = 'inline-block';
      row.style.cssText = 'height: 50px; width:50px;';
      row.style.border = 'solid';
      row.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

      container.appendChild(row);
    }
  }

  return container;
};

console.log(createGrid());
```

```html
<container>
</container>
Hi, I am new to using d.o.m and am trying to create this function that creates a 16x16 grid in the HTML. I am using javascript to create the html and css. However, whenever i return the function it is undefined. What am I doing wrong?
```